How to make a GET request to return Entity Registration form fields?
I am using Drupal as a decoupled CMS with Entity Registration module, and would like to get the Registration Type form fields to display on my SPA.
I have enabled the REST resource:
/entity/entity_form_display/{entity_form_display}
I am making the GET request replacing entity_form_display with the ID of my Registration Type 'myform' showing in the URL here:
/admin/structure/registration-types/{type}/edit
Curl/ Postman URL:
http://mydomain.com/entity/entity_form_display/myform?_format=json

I get 404 Not Found:
"message": "The \"entity_form_display\" parameter was not converted for the path \"/entity/entity_form_display/{entity_form_display}\" (route name: \"rest.entity.entity_form_display.GET\")"

ChatGPT is suggesting "
I specify {entity_form_display} as a parameter in the endpoint definition for a Drupal REST API resource by defining a custom route .."
I am hoping, and do not believe I need to do this, as the entity resource shows to be enabled in Drupal admin.
I have no trouble making REST requests to other resources.
Drupal 10.2.5
PHP 8.3.6
Entity Registration 3.1
Simple OAuth 5.2
Serialization
EDIT
After viewing Admin > Devel > Routes Info, I created a route:
http://myurl/jsonapi/entity_form_display/entity_form_display/{entity}

Where I have replaced entity with registration.mytype.default this returns a data object that does include the custom fields, but the fields are not sortable or filterable:
{"data": { "attributes": {
        "langcode": "en-gb",
        "status": true,
        "content": {
            "anon_mail": {
                "type": "email_default",
                "weight": 0,
                "region": "content",
                "settings": {
                    "placeholder": "",
                    "size": 60
                },
                "third_party_settings": []
            },
            "field_place": {
                "type": "string_textfield",
                "weight": 100,
                "region": "content",
                "settings": {
                    "size": 60,
                    "placeholder": ""
                },
                "third_party_settings": []
            },
            "field_name": {
                "type": "string_textfield",
                "weight": 1,
                "region": "content",
                "settings": {
                    "size": 60,
                    "placeholder": ""
                },
                "third_party_settings": []
            },
            "state": {
                "type": "registration_state_default",
                "weight": 4,
                "region": "content",
                "settings": [],
                "third_party_settings": []
            }

        },
    ...
    }
  }
}

Included in the data object is a dependencies object listing module properties:
      "dependencies": {
            "config": [
                "field.field.registration.mytype.field_email",
                "field.field.registration.mytype.field_name",
                "field.field.registration.mytype.field_party",
                "field.field.registration.mytype.field_role",
                "registration.type.mytype"
            ],
            "module": [
                "registration"
            ]
        },

Is there a way to query on these? I believe what I need is to able to return the fields of a custom entity type's  bundle, then I can sort by weight etc.
I would be very grateful for some guidance on this.
Thanks for your time.
